# Loop NOT Breaking as Expected After User Input

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

This question applies to step #3 in the code below. I am trying to write a for loop that appends a list and breaks when the total number of elements in the list reaches 5. I have tried a few different solutions, but the loop will only break when the number of list elements reaches 6. In other words, the code is intended to ask for two inputs then break, but it asks for three inputs before breaking. I am not sure why. I any appreciate any feedback, and thank you in advance! I should also say I am just starting to learn Python and am only using techniques I've learned in my course of study so far.

Here two solutions I've tried:

```
# step 1
beatles = []
print("Step 1:", beatles)

# step 2
beatles.append("John Lennon")
beatles.append("Paul McCartney")
beatles.append("George Harrison")
print("Step 2:", beatles)

# step 3
for i in range(len(beatles)):
    if i == 5:
        break
    beatles.append(input("Enter the name of a beatles: "))
print("Step 3:", beatles)
```

Comment: `len(beatles)` is 3 so `i` can never get to 4 or 3 for that matter. Perhaps rather than `for i in range(len(beatles)):` you tried `while True:` and tested for `len(beatles) >= 4` inside to break on.

Comment: `while len(beatles) < 5: beatles.append(input("Next Beatle: "))` but who is the [5th Beatle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_Beatle)?

Answer (score 0):

Since `len(beatles) == 3` per:

```py
beatles = []
beatles.append("John Lennon")
beatles.append("Paul McCartney")
beatles.append("George Harrison")
```

The for loop can never set `i` to anything more than 2

```
print(list(range(len(beatles))))
```

Shows you that the `for` loop currently only iterates with values of `i` in `[0, 1, 2]`

Since we want to add up to 5 beatles, let's create a looping strategy that repeats until `len(beatles) == 5`.

```
# step 2
beatles = []
beatles.append("John Lennon")
beatles.append("Paul McCartney")
beatles.append("George Harrison")

# step 3
while len(beatles) != 5:
    beatles.append(input("Enter the name of a beatle: "))

print(beatles)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Your code showed all three steps repeating identically, which I suspect was a double-pasting error, so I deleted the redundant repeated code.)

WHen your loop begins, `len(beatles)` is `3`. So `range(len(beatles))` – the values that `i` will step through on each loop – will be essentially `[0, 1, 2]`.

As a result, the loop will happen 3 times – once for each of `i=0`, `i=1`, & `i=2` – prompting the user for 3 more names, but variable `i` will never be `5`, so there will never be an early `break`.

It seems your *intent* might be matched by changing the `if i == 5:` test to be `if len(beatles) == 5:`. Then, after two loops (`i=0` and `i=1`), the value of `len(beatles)` will in fact be `5`, achieving an early-exit.

But, that code is still a bit silly. Why arrange a loop over the 3 `i` values `[0, 1, 2]` if your real goal at start of loop is just to request exactly 2 more names? To request exactly 2 more names, you could instead do:

```
for _ in range(5 - len(beatles)):
    beatles.append(input("Enter the name of a beatles: "))
```

Here, I've used just `_` as the variable name, a common convention for cases where you don't even need to check the actual loop variable. I've arranged for the loop to happen `(5 - len(beatles))` times – 2 times – because that's what's needed to get from `len(beatles)` to `5`. And thus no `break` is actually required.

Another option would be to use a `while` loop instead:

```
while(len(beatles) < 5):
    beatles.append(input("Enter the name of a beatles: "))
```

This will explicitly keep asking until `len(beatles)` is 5 (or higher) – again no `break` needed, because normal operation of the loop is sufficient without special-case early-exits.